# Allure not create body and attachements with java 11

Tags: java, automation, allure

When i start `mvn clean test site` and test failure, allure need attach screenshot and body,but on the Java 11 body and attachements not creating.
That is also for Steps.Probably it depends on Java version and aspectJ library.

On the Java 8 it's working
No exceptions is shown.

Maybe some ideas how to configure with Java 11

#### Here pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <compiler.version>11</compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.0</maven.surefire.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <appium.version>7.0.0</appium.version>
        <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>

        <allure.testng.version>2.8.1</allure.testng.version>
        <allure.maven.plugin.version>2.9</allure.maven.plugin.version>
        <allure.report.version>2.7.0</allure.report.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.1</aspectj.version>
        <jetty.maven.plugin.version>9.4.12.RC2</jetty.maven.plugin.version>

        <exclude.tag></exclude.tag>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
          <build>
            <plugins> 
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                      <suiteXmlFile>
                        src/test/resources/testng.xml
                      </suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        --illegal-access=permit
                    </argLine>
                    <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                   </argLine>
                    <excludedGroups>${exclude.tag}</excludedGroups>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${compiler.version}</source>
                    <target>${compiler.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>
                      ${project.build.directory}\site\allure-maven-plugin
                    </webAppSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
       </build>

    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${allure.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that AspectJ supports Java 11 since version [1.9.2](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-192.html). You are using `1.9.1`.